# Menubars in X servers, clients, window managers

Tags: c, x11, xlib

Recently I'm writing a simple window manager using X11, just to learn more! Now I want to know:

1. How can I add a menubar to a window? (when writing application)
2. How window managers detects, manage and show windows menubar?

Comment: Are you talking about WM menu? For example, pop up when you click on icon in window title bar? On a low level ( x11 / xlib ) there is no concept of menu, just "windows"  ( rectangular areas on screen that can get input and be used to draw things )

Comment: Actually I'm talking about menubar on top of each window! File, Edit, View, ...

Comment: usually that's not WM job to do, and higher level concept that does not exist in xlib. Preferred way is to you use ui toolkit like gtk or qt. If you know for sure that on target system there is a global service that implements menu you can try to talk to this service directly ( My old attemt with node dbus client: https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbusmenu )

Answer (score 3):

> How can I add a menubar to a window?

One should use an X toolkit such as Qt or Gtk, but in principle one can concoct a menubar by just drawing it like any other window content. Of course the latter would be very tedious and error-prone, but it's doable (eventually).

> How window managers detects, manage and show windows menubar?

They normally don't. A specific WM may know about client menubars via some kind of **non-standard** protocol that should be supported by both WM and clients. There are no menubar-related APIs in the [ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html). There are menu-related APIs in the [desktop.org WM specs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/wm-spec/) but those pertain to tear-off and pop-up menus, not menubars per se. X toolkits already deal with these appropriately so application writers shouldn't do anything special.